# How to load JQuery ui into chrome extension content scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load jquery ui into chrome extension.

I've succedded load `jquery.js`, `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` but when I open a dialog,
the images of the dialog (like the x of close button) aren't shown and I get the warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: ...
```

I also tried to change the `jquery-ui.css` from `images/image_name` to `chrome://extension/__extension__ID__/images/image_name`. Then I get the error:

```
not allowed to load local resource: ...
```

What is the right way to do it?

My manifest.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "my_extension",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "description": "bla bla",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/"
    ],
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery-1.10.2.js" , "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" ],
        "css": [ "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Run",
        "default_icon": "Run.png"
    },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it a web_accesible_resource from the manifest and use chrome.extension.getUrl to get its actual url

Comment: The problem is that the images path inside the jquery-ui.css

Comment: Yes. Set it from code not css. Also try getting the path so you know how it looks like and hardcode it on the css bit that will break when you load the extension as developer (locally)